# Defining static variable of enum type in c++

Tags: c++

```
class Game
{
public:
    static void Start();

private:
    static bool IsExiting();
    static void GameLoop();

    static void ShowSplashScreen();
    static void ShowMenu();

    enum GameState { Uninitialized, ShowingSplash, Paused,
                    ShowingMenu, Playing, Exiting };

    Game::GameState Game::_gameState = Game::Uninitialized;
    static sf::RenderWindow _mainWindow;
};
Game::GameState Game::_gameState;
RenderWindow Game::_mainWindow;
```

Error is now in function that runs first

```
void processEvents(){// error: first defined here ???
    Event event;
    while(App.pollEvent(event)){
        if(event.type == Event::Closed)
                App.close();
    }
}
```

And there are also other error such as multiple definition of `Game::_gameState' in function it gives the same errors in other functions that are declared in Game class

```
void Game::Start(void) { // multiple definition of `Game::_gameState'
    if (_gameState != Uninitialized)
        return;

    _mainWindow.create(VideoMode(1200, 900, 32), "Game",
            Style::Close);
    _gameState = Game::ShowingSplash;

    while (!IsExiting()) {
        GameLoop();
    }

    _mainWindow.close();
}
```

I fixed the errors but one more showed up

```
while (!IsExiting()) {  //undefined reference to Game::IsExiting
    GameLoop();
}

_mainWindow.close();
```

}

I don't know it is static bool function other functions works fine but this one is bool and gives me errors

Comment: Try `Game::Gamestate` in your declaration.

Comment: @lstmeyxc, repost the errors you obtain as a separate question, or update your question with where the error is now seen.

Comment: @Itsmeyxc: We are clearly not going to track your edits and sub-sequent questions. This is not a chat, right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `enum GameState` is contained within `class Game` you need to scope the variable accordingly:

```
Game::GameState Game::_gameState;
```

Comment: I did that but it show now more error look it in my edited questions

Comment: You need to put the definition of the gamestate variable in a code (.c or .cpp) file, not in a header.  When you include the header in multiple files it is attempting to define the same variable multiple times

Comment: That cleard almost all of errors now it gives me one about undefind reference to function that is static bool i edited the questions look it up

Answer (score 4):

`GameState` enum is declared in the scope of `Game` class. Thus, when you reference it outside that class's scope, you have to use fully qualified type name (this includes defining the instance of `_gameState` field. I also recommend you give it some initial value. For example:

```
Game::GameState Game::_gameState = Game::Uninitialized;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried that but give me error at first function that runs look at the question i edited it.

Comment: @Itsmeyxc: Now you have multiple definitions. It is a different problem and has nothing to do with your original question. Thus I recommend you ask a separate question on these new problems you have.